# 端末上の emacs で、メニューの選択肢で「戻る」を実行するには？

Tags: emacs

端末上の emacs では、<kbd>f10</kbd> を実行すると、メニューを選択して、`C-f`,`C-b`,`C-p`,`C-n` でメニュー項目の移動ができます。

RET によって、項目の選択(ドリルダウン)ができますが、選択した状態から一つ上の階層へ戻る方法がわからずにいます。このコマンドはどのキーにバインドされていますか?

Comment: 2年半くらい前のメールですが、[Drop-down menus, popup menus, and popup dialogs supported on TTYs](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel/164053) の最後の方に "I did not find a way from the sub menu back to the main menu ... navigation would improve this?" "Not easy to do. Patches are welcome." とあります。これは現在でも改善されていない様ですね…。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(コメントを転記しています。)

2年半 *(現時点では3年..?)* くらい前のメールですが、[Drop-down menus, popup menus, and popup dialogs supported on TTYs](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel/164053) の最後の方に "I did not find a way from the sub menu back to the main menu ... navigation would improve this?" "Not easy to do. Patches are welcome." とあります。これは現在でも改善されていない様ですね…。